# Update mapView pin colour based on boolean property

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to update the colour of the `mapView` pins based on whether the hotspot has been visited or not.

See my code below. Below is the hotspot class that subscribes to the `MKAnnotation` delegate. The property that determines pin colour is the visited Bool.

```
init(title: String, hotspotName: String,coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, ARType:String, hotspotId:String)
{
    //assing values to properties
    self.hotspotTitle = title
    self.hotspotName = hotspotName
    self.ARType = ARType
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.hotspotId = hotspotId
    super.init()
}

var visited: Bool {
    return self.completed
}

var title: String?
{
    return hotspotTitle
}

var subtitle: String?
{

    return hotspotName
}
```

Below is the mapKit delegate method I'm using to try and update pin colour.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    // check if annotation is of type Hotspot, as we dont want to alter other types of annotations
    guard annotation is Hotspot else {
        return  nil
    }

    let identifier = "Hotspot"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
    let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation,reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    if annotationView == nil
    {

        if let hotspot = annotationView?.annotation as? Hotspot {
            if !hotspot.visited
            {

                pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red:0.32, green:0.82, blue:0.4, alpha:1)
                pinView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
            }
            else
            {
                pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red:0.0, green:0.0, blue:0.90, alpha:1)
                pinView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)


            }
        }


        pinView.frame = mapView.frame
        pinView.isEnabled = true
        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        pinView.animatesDrop = true
        let rightButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        rightButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(getDirections),for: .touchUpInside)
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
        annotationView = pinView

    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView
    {

        annotationView.annotation = annotation


        // 5
        let button = annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView as! UIButton
        if let index = trail.hotspots.index(of: annotation as! Hotspot)
        {

            button.tag = index
        }
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Try a not so smart code to remove all annotation views from MKMapView and add them again 
This code is to remove the annotations 
`let allAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations
self.mapView.removeAnnotations(allAnnotations)`
and use the same code that you used to add them again every time the property visited of an annotation change

Another way is to loop all annotation views and remove only the annotation with the coordinates that are same with the annotation that the value changed and add it again

Comment: Also check if the method you use is called and not the method
`func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
        <#code#>
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Update mapView pin colour out of `if annotationView == nil` statement.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    // check if annotation is of type Hotspot, as we dont want to alter other types of annotations
    guard annotation is Hotspot else {
        return  nil
    }

    let identifier = "Hotspot"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
    let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation,reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    if annotationView == nil
    {
        pinView.frame = mapView.frame
        pinView.isEnabled = true
        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        pinView.animatesDrop = true
        let rightButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        rightButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(getDirections),for: .touchUpInside)
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
        annotationView = pinView
    }

    if let hotspot = annotationView?.annotation as? Hotspot {
        if !hotspot.visited
        {
            annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red:0.32, green:0.82, blue:0.4, alpha:1)
            annotationView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red:0.0, green:0.0, blue:0.90, alpha:1)
            annotationView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
        }
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView
    {

        annotationView.annotation = annotation


        // 5
        let button = annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView as! UIButton
        if let index = trail.hotspots.index(of: annotation as! Hotspot)
        {

            button.tag = index
        }
    }

    return annotationView
}
```